# JavaScript: return undefined instead of Object

Tags: javascript, return

Can anyone explain me:
why is this wrong:

```
if (current <= last) {
    //here!
    return
    {
        done: false,
        value: current++
    };
} else {
    return
    {
        done: true
    };
}
```

and this is right ?

```
if (current <= last) {
    //error here
    return {
        done: false,
        value: current++
    };
} else {
    return {
        done: true
    };
}
```

In both cases code returns object, but when i moving first brace of object to a new line code stop working.

Comment: @Tushar Thats not a doublicate of the Question you marked. But there is another similar question out there.

Comment: @CodeiSir Can you post link of it

Comment: @Tushar I can't find it, but I edited the Title of this post so it will be easier to find in he future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "return" and then new line is a complete statement wich will return nothing, because there is nothing after `return`, it returns `undefined`.

It's as if you would write `return;`